# No bootable device error after resizing filesystem partition

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, boot-repair

Im quite new to Ubuntu platform. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 recently with 50GB allocated to file system partition.  Then i needed to install virtualbox and the size of the file system partition wasn't enough. So i had to resize my file system partition with Gparted. After i have increased my machine isnt starting and it gives an No bootable device error. i have run Boot repair and got the URL as http://paste.ubuntu.com/10653508/. Could some one help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run resize2fs after you changed the partition size?

Comment: No. I Resized my filesystem partition and applied the changes in Gparted. Then i restarted the system. :(

Comment: OK; so you've got an UEFI partition on a veruy small SSD drive, but you still have boot files on your SDA?  How are you booting?  UEFI or BIOS mode?  And why the ntfs partition? Do you have windows as well?